# Как вытащить данные из запроса к БД в node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Привет! Как вытащить данные из запроса к БД функцией connection.query в node.js и передать в html? Заранее спасибо.На просторах интернета нашла пример (Не работает):

```
### `mysql.js`
    var http = require('http');
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var fs = require('fs');

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
     database : 'mysql',
     user     : 'root',
     password : 'toor'
    });

    var x={};

    var query = function(){
    connection.connect();
    connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      x = rows[0].solution;
    });
    connection.end();
    };

    var answer = function(){
     return x;
    };

    module.exports.query = query;
    module.exports.answer = answer;

    var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
     response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
     var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf8');
     myReadStream.pipe(response);
     });
    server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
    console.log('Прослушивание порта 3000');
```

###`index.html`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
       <title>Hello World2!</title>
       <script>
        var mysql = require('./mysql.js');
        function bodyOnLoad(){
         mysql.query();
        };

        function getAnswer(){
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = mysql.answer();
        }
      </script>
     </head>
      <body onload="bodyOnLoad();">
       <div id="answer" onClick="getAnswer;">Click me</div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Не вижу в вопросе использования nodejs. Начните с поднятия веб-сервера на ноде...

Comment: @PavelMayorov поднятие сервера там как раз есть. Как и `require` серверных библиотек на клиенте :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev это он уже после моего комментария добавил...

Comment: всё ещё нужна помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте шаблонизатор и какой-то http-фреймворк для удобства.
Например для Express и шаблонизатора handlebars, передача данных в html будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
router.get("/", function(res, req, next){
    connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
        res.render("index.hbs", data: rows}     
    });

})
```

А потом в вашем .hbs (читайте .html) документе можно будет вывести

```
<div id="data">{{data.yourdata}}</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как можно реализовать без использования шаблонизатора, express? интереса ради)

Comment: @Blackbonny ну это будет сложнее и потребует написания большего количества кода. Ну можно создать простенькое api с данными, но без знаний node.js даже этого просто так не сделать...

Comment: спасибо, буду изучать.